# asp.net 4.5 mvc 4 site shows "This page can’t be displayed" when I run it in VS2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am having trouble running my Asp.Net 4.5 MVC 4 site on `Windows Server 2012 R2`. When I run my site, I get `This page can’t be displayed` error. The execution does not even reach any controller code and this error page is showed. I checked the app by directly running it in VS2012 as well as deploying it in IIS 8 but same error page is showed. I have to use IE and cannot check it in another browser.

I tried googling but it did not help.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

The *Default Web Site* (containing iisstart.html) in IIS also does not work and gives the same error. I suppose that there is some issue with the IIS itself.

Any help on how to fix this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check security for your app folder? IIS_IUSRS must have read and execute rights, at least.